# Gate switching - Guitar signal gate controlled by another signal

Tags: circuit-design, audio, gate-driving, guitar-pedal, analog-switch

The circuit below is based on a noise gate and a JFET based switching circuits. The idea is to mute the guitar signal when another signal pases certain threshold of volume (like a reversed gate triggered by an external signal gate). The result of this would be like a hard sidechain controlled by a signal that mutes the main signal and then comes back when the gate signal falls.

Here is the circuit (edited with some good points from the comments):
[image: Gate circuit]

First signal gate enters a circuit which is amplified with a transistor and then it is rectified with D1 and D2 (this part is based on another noise gate style circuit).

Then, the other part is a guitar JFET switching circuit, which uses an audio JFET with biased voltage with some decoupling to switch mute or unmute the signal depending on Q5. The idea is that when signal gate passes certain volume will able to drive Q5 to ground, so it will drive the JFET Q4 gate to ground, muting the main signal in the process, and then, when the signal gate is below certain level, Q5 will not pull down Q4 into ground and will unmute the input signal.

My questions are (apart from if you see some flaws in the design, resistor values etc...): Will +9V into R5 drive the Q4 JFET to close the switching circuit when Q5 is not pulling it down to ground?

Is it possible to put like a decay potentiometer which makes the signal return from muting really fast (like an instant kill switch) to more like a ramp up to simulate like a swell typical of sidechain compressors depending on the potentiometer?

Also, will I need some buffers on the main signal or will it work only with some simple decoupling capacitors?

Edited:

Added capacitor C2 to the VDIV divisor for uncoupling and also bigger R8 and R9 (before they were 10K now 1M).

C3 from the collector of Q5 to ground to soften the switching. Also changed R3 position to connect directly to 9V (as Jens commented below it was a mistake).

Comment: I would advise you to simulate the circuit and perform a lot of the evaluation yourself. This is what an EE pro would likely do.

Comment: I think the upper end of R3 should be connected to +9 V.

Comment: Ah yes, I mistakenly I put R3 after R5, it should be connected before to 9V.

Answer (score 0):

VDIV needs strong decoupling. As shown it is not a low impedance point, so R6 and R7 form a bypass path for the signal

R3 and C2 form the sustain time constant for the switch, the amount of time it waits during no-signal before it releases the JFET to conduct. As shown, I think it is so short that the FET will be turning on and off with individual cycles of the gate signal.

To soften the release, add a capacitor from the Q5 collector to GND.  This cap plus R5 set the release slope.

Comment: For decoupling VDIV can I put a capacitor from the VDIV node to ground?

How you would implement the potentiometer on the R3 C2? I didn't understand that part.

I did put a Cap on Q5 collector and it work great in the simulator, I didn't had to change R5, as R5 sets also the voltage on the gate of the JFET and messed up my threshold voltage (or maybe that's what you meant by release).